# Why does this Ubuntu 20.04.5 freeze / hang during boot?

Tags: boot, 20.04, freeze, lts

distro : `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS 64bit`

kernel : `5.15.0-58-generic`

symptoms : system freezes or hangs at boot at exactly the same location. The cursor blinks about 30 times, and then freezes. The screen output is shown :

- [screenshot of boot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oez08.png)

CTRL-ALT-DEL works fine. The network is fine after recovery menu. Mounted USBs work fine. The "entire" log is included at the bottom of this post.  likely culprits : nVidia. Wayland. gdm3 , gnome issues, or some combination of those.

## Wayland

journalctl errors related to gdm-wayland-session.

```
Jan 17 20:31:50 Tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1523]: dbus-daemon[1523]: [session uid=125 pid=1523] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.1' (uid=125 pid=1524 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jan 17 20:31:50 Tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1523]: dbus-daemon[1523]: [session uid=125 pid=1523] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.2' (uid=125 pid=1524 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jan 17 20:31:50 Tower gnome-session[1524]: gnome-session-binary[1524]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jan 17 20:31:50 Tower gnome-session[1524]: gnome-session-binary[1524]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jan 17 20:31:50 Tower gnome-session-binary[1524]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jan 17 20:31:50 Tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1523]: dbus-daemon[1523]: [session uid=125 pid=1523] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.2' (uid=125 pid=1524 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jan 17 20:31:50 Tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1523]: dbus-daemon[1523]: [session uid=125 pid=1523] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.2' (uid=125 pid=1524 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jan 17 20:31:50 Tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1523]: dbus-daemon[1523]: [session uid=125 pid=1523] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.2' (uid=125 pid=1524 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jan 17 20:31:50 Tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1523]: dbus-daemon[1523]: [session uid=125 pid=1523] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.2' (uid=125 pid=1524 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jan 17 20:31:50 Tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1523]: dbus-daemon[1523]: [session uid=125 pid=1523] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.2' (uid=125 pid=1524 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower gnome-session[1524]: gnome-session-binary[1524]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower gnome-session[1524]: gnome-session-binary[1524]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower gnome-session-binary[1524]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower gnome-session-binary[1524]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
```

## gnome

journalctl errors related to gnome-shell and gnome-session-binary

```
Jan 17 20:31:54 Tower systemd[1487]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
Jan 17 20:31:54 Tower systemd[1487]: Startup finished in 9.657s.
Jan 17 20:31:55 Tower gnome-shell[1594]: Failed to create backend: No GPUs with outputs found
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower gnome-session[1524]: gnome-session-binary[1524]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower gnome-session-binary[1524]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower gnome-session-binary[1524]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower gdm-launch-environment][1480]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower gdm3[1473]: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Succeeded.
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower systemd-logind[1270]: Session c1 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower systemd-logind[1270]: Removed session c1.
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower gdm3[1473]: Child process -1515 was already dead.
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower systemd[1]: plymouth-start.service: Succeeded.
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower systemd[1]: plymouth-quit-wait.service: Succeeded.
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower systemd[1]: Finished Hold until boot process finishes up.
```

## gdm

Errors related to gdm3

```
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower gdm3[1473]: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower gdm3[1473]: Child process -1515 was already dead.
Jan 17 20:31:56 Tower gdm3[1672]: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-58-generic
Jan 17 20:32:06 Tower gdm3[1697]: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-58-generic
Jan 17 20:32:16 Tower gdm3[1473]: Child process -1515 was already dead.
Jan 17 20:32:18 Tower gdm3[1473]: Tried to look up non-existent conversation gdm-launch-environment
Jan 17 20:32:18 Tower gdm3[1825]: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-58-generic
Jan 17 20:32:28 Tower gdm3[1473]: Freeing conversation 'gdm-launch-environment' with active job
Jan 17 20:32:28 Tower gdm3[1860]: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-58-generic
```

## log

Uninterrupted log containing all the above errors in their context.  The entire log, is of course, much longer than this.

```
Unfortunately, I could not include the entire boot log.  askubuntu website keeps marking it as "spam".
```

Comment: You mention 64-bit, but not which 64 bit architecture;  ie. *arm64*, *ppc64el*, .. *amd64* are all 64-bit yet different architectures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)